# Add text in every word of a multi value variable

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following variable

```
var="text1 value1.text value2"
```

I want to add specific characters at the start and the end of every word in variable

Τhe desired result I want it to be the following

```
[text1] [value1.text] [value2]
```

As far I can only add text only in all variable content

```
echo [$var]
```

output

```
[text1 value1.text value2]
```

Can you help me how to do it

preferably with awk

Comment: Would it make sense to store this as an array, e.g. `var=("text1" "value1.text" "value2")`? If each "word" is a separate thing, this is usually a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i = "[" $i "]"} 1' <<< "$var"

[text1] [value1.text] [value2]
```

Or a gnu-awk solution without looping:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '{$0 = "[" $0 "]"; ORS=RT} 1' <<< "$var"

[text1] [value1.text] [value2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want to change the value of `var` or just output the contents of `var` with the square brackets added so take your pick:

```
$ var='text1 value1.text value2'
```

```
$ echo "[${var// /] [}]"
[text1] [value1.text] [value2]
```

```
$ var="[${var// /] [}]"
$ echo "$var"
[text1] [value1.text] [value2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set -f 
var="text1 value1.text value2"
printf -v var "[%s] " $var
echo "${var% }"
```

Output:

```
[text1] [value1.text] [value2]
```